# Analyze and instruments

Tags: objective-c, ios, memory-management, memory-leaks, instruments

Well, that question may sound silly, but...
When I run my app in analyze mode or with instruments I get no possible (analyze mode) or memory (instruments) leaks. 
Does it mean that my app is 100% memory leaks free ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. For one thing, you'd have to run every possible execution path/state sequence in your app to definitively say that there are no leaks by simple testing. More importantly, true memory leaks, where you don't release memory but no longer have a reference to it are all the leaks instrument is able to detect.

However, those are *not* the only similar problem you can create. You can also easily not discard data that you no longer actually need, causing memory to build up. This isn't a true leak, as you still have a reference to the data in question, it's just that you haven't released it and gotten rid of your reference to it.

You can still find this kind of problem using the allocations instrument. It won't explicitly flag problems, but it will allow you to see if you're allocating lots of memory that you don't later release. On iOS in particular, it's important to make sure that you give up allocated memory when you no longer need it, or your app's memory usage will grow until the OS terminates your app.

Comment: Well, I did some tests and I think that I have the problem that you notice at the third paragraph. I have a small increase of memory (live bytes) against testing with Allocations. That part of code just switch between two views. I believe this is a problem, right ? Live bytes shows grow of memory usage with about 20kb per ~10 time while switching between the views.

Comment: Yup-- that could be a problem.  Or it could be a cache that'll eventually be pruned.   Heapshot analysis is the next step.  http://www.friday.com/bbum/2010/10/17/when-is-a-leak-not-a-leak-using-heapshot-analysis-to-find-undesirable-memory-growth/

Comment: I'm gonna check that. Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

That really depends on how well you tested it with leaks but keep in mind that as hard as Leaks tries its not bulletproof, though if you do a through job you can be reasonably sure about your app.  Don't forget to also use instruments other than leaks, the allocations tool is useful in picking up on abandoned memory which just Leaks won't point out to you but can be just as troublesome.

Answer (score -1):

Your app does not run when you analyze, instead the static analyzer looks at your code. Regarding the instruments, check that your profile configuration (in edit scheme) is set to debug. Otherwise your app will be stripped out of symbols and the leaks instrument won't work.

Comment: Not true;  leaks works as well as it ever does with or without symbols.

Answer (score -2):

you can assume it is in the best state now in which it could be.

Comment: Not by a long shot.   There are about a zillion ways you can allocate memory that is neither a leak nor something the analyzer will detect, that will still lead to crashes due to memory exhaustion.